# How to utilize Neutron independently with veths？

Tags: networking, openstack

I'm new to OpenStack and currently interested in the Neutron part of it. What I'm seeking is some advice about how to utilize Neutron independently, to build a virtual network, for Docker containers maybe.

Suppose I've already got Neutron and Keystone installed on controller node and compute nodes. I guess the following steps are required to test a virtual network (imaging myself as Nova).

1. create a *network*
2. create a *subnet*
3. create two pairs of veths (each pair represents a vm/container)

*for each pair of them:*

4. create a *port* for one end of the veth pair (passing veth's mac address as a parameter)
5. attach another end of the veth pair to ovs bridge
6. ping from one veth pair to another

The above is my general idea, don't know if it is correct and don't know the operation details either.

Expecting your suggestions, any links are appreciated.

Comment: But ... Docker already has that functionality from what I understand?

Comment: @Seth Oh? Can you paste any links?

Comment: [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/) just look for the networking options. Docker already uses virtual networking on the host. It's not really clear what your actual goal here would be.

Comment: @Seth Ah. I'm not making it clear. Yes Docker has several networking options support, while I'm seeking a way that using Neutron to create port, security groups, qos, etc, and, letting Docker containers use those ports managed by Neutron.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at OpenStack Kuryr (https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Kuryr), the project in charge of bringing Neutron networking to docker containers.